# Testo turistico spagnolo-italiano: «brillar por sí sola»

Tags: translation

Devo tradurre un testo turistico dallo spagnolo all'italiano della Costa Tropical (Granada). Questo testo comincia così: «Esta privilegiada costa **brilla por sí sola** con [...]».

Ho cercato degli equivalenti in italiano per questa espressione ma non trovo niente di adatto. Potrebbe andare bene **«brillare a luce propria»** come traduzione?

Accetto ogni suggerimento, grazie a tutti per l'aiuto.

Comment: Che cosa significa in spagnolo?

Comment: @DaG: Penso che "brilla di luce propria" renda bene quello che significa l'espressione in spagnolo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Brillare di luce propria*** è l'esperssione corretta in italiano.

L'espressione fa riferimento al significato letterale come in: "le stelle brillano di luce propria". In senso figurato significa che il soggetto in questione ha qualità e caratteristiche così belle ed apprezzabili da non aver bisogno di ulteriori commenti.

In [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=brillare%20di%20luce%20propria&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbrillare%20di%20luce%20propria%3B%2Cc0) puoi trovare altri esempi in cui l'espressione viene usata.